# Coding inside HTML 4 Boxes

Tags: html, inline-styles

I need to code inside an HTML box in a CMS system as you can see in the picture.

I have never coded with inline-style only style sheets.

This is what I can write the HTML code with inline-style on. It's inside an HTML CMS box:

[image]

It's got to look like this ideally - 4 boxes with text, no stylesheet:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the HTML in your normal IDE and then copy/paste it into the HTML part of the CMS control.

Rather than having the Styles in a stylesheet, put them inside the same file as the html in a style tag, then reference the classes as you would normally if reading from a style sheet.

e.g.

```
<style>
.style { font-color:red; }
</style>

<p class="style"></p>
```